# After any request and response, call an api

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I need to call api by checking some condition. But this api call is needed after any request / response. But I couldn't find anything useful for this.

So, I am looking for a solution to setup the project using redux-saga so that I can call an api on any request / response.

For eg. we can have different api calls from different places;

```
.fetch('/books')
.fetch('/copies')
etc.
```

Now, I want also to call an api on every fetch (before request and after response). Hope, this is now clear.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question and show some code of yours so that we can actually help you out here?

Comment: I think I have elaborated my issue clearly. But I cannot provide the code since I don't know how to call an api after any/every request/response. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried effectmiddlwares in redux-saga: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/Testing.md#effectmiddlwares ?

Comment: that seems to be for testing. can you provide an answer with real code?

Comment: https://www.javascriptjanuary.com/blog/may-cause-side-effects-how-to-implement-redux-sagas-as-middleware

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a reliable way to identify actions that are responses you can use a `pattern` function to match all response actions and trigger another call.

For example:

```
// assuming your response success action types all look like "REQUEST_TYPE_SUCCESS"
function isResponse(action) {
    return action.type.endsWith("SUCCESS")
}

function* makeApiCall(action) {
    // maybe do some logic to determine the api call based on the action
    yield call(asyncApiCall, args);
}

function* responseWatcher() {
    // consider takeLatest or takeLeading instead of takeEvery depending on your use case
    yield takeEvery(isResponse, makeApiCall);
}
```

And then add `responseWatcher` to your root saga however you are setting that up.

See the api reference for `take` if you need more info on the `pattern` arg to the `take` helpers: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takepattern